# Cannot find module "react-slick"

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm trying to use react-slick inside my React project.
When I try to import it

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';
```

I get this error

```
Cannot find module "react-slick"
```

Anyone else having this issue ?

https://github.com/akiran/react-slick
Installation

```
npm install react-slick
```

Also install slick-carousel for css and font

```
npm install slick-carousel
```

React V "react@^15.4.1"

NPM install results

```
npm install react-slick --save
(node:14297) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
fb-lite@1.1.0 ..blal
└─┬ react-slick@0.14.5 
  ├─┬ json2mq@0.2.0 
  │ └── string-convert@0.2.1 
  ├─┬ react-responsive-mixin@0.4.0 
  │ ├── can-use-dom@0.1.0 
  │ └── enquire.js@2.1.1 
  └─┬ slick-carousel@1.6.0 
    └── jquery@3.1.1 


npm install slick-carousel --save
(node:14298) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
fb-lite@1.1.0 ..blal
└── slick-carousel@1.6.0
```

Comment: There's not enough context to help you with this question. Can you show the output of the `npm install react-slick` and the `package.json` before and after?

Comment: Just added the npm install results in the above post

Comment: Great, looks normal -- what does the `package.json` look like? Could you also post the file you're importing the troublesome libraries into?

Comment: what happens if you do `var Slider = require('react-slick');` instead of import?

Comment: Same thing when I use require like above. The file i'm importing into is just a regular js file with other imports that are fine. When I comment out the react-slick import all if fine again.

Comment: Has anyone else been able to get it to work ?

Comment: Yes I can use it, you have to declare `var Slider = require('react-slick')` instead of an import. I use this version of the library =>  "react-slick": "^0.14.6", make sure that you don't have a too old release or wrong library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your react component file:
import Slider from 'react-slick';

In package.json check version : 
"react-slick": "^0.15.4"

this is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

**I have faced the same problem.**
**Please run the below command:-**

```
yarn remove react-slick // If you installed through yarn

 or

npm uninstall react-slick // If you installed through npm

then run:-

npm install react-slick --save
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
rm -rf node_modules

delete package-lock.json

npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked when I change from this

**import Slider from "react-slick";**

to this

**import Slider from 'react-slick';**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
npm uninstall react-slick --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and Install `react-slick` again.
If that's not working, then check the modules in the package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
"react-slick": "^0.28.1",
"react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
"reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
"slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"   }
```